# reverse proxy RabbitMQ request on IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, rabbitmq

I use rabbitmq on my windows server and I want send request from client to server by use URL not server ip address .
so I set up URL rewriter on IIS with this role ( {C:1}://127.0.0.1:5672/{R:1}) but it's not work.
I realize that URL rewriter not support amqp protocol and I install stomp plugin for rabbitmq and change client code and IIS role to ( {C:1}://127.0.0.1:61613/{R:1}) but the client can't send message outside of server .

the test program work fine inside of  server and send message correctly but when data pass by IIS the message not receive

this is client code :

```
  var facConnection = new ConnectionFactory()
        {
            HostName = "https://rabbitmq.mysite.com",
            UserName = "guest",
            Password = "guest",
            VirtualHost = "/",
        };

        var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Message");


        using var connection = facConnection.CreateConnection();
        using var channel = connection.CreateModel();

        channel.QueueDeclare("test", false, false, false, null);
        channel.BasicPublish("", routingKey: "test", body: body);
```

and this is error message :

"None of the specified endpoints were reachable"

Comment: IIS ARR can only be configured as reverse proxy for HTTP protocol, so your wish won't come true by default. You have to enable HTTP support on RabbitMQ side first, such as Web STOMP https://www.rabbitmq.com/web-stomp.html (not the STOMP).

Comment: @LexLi thanks a lot . can you guide me for iis role and net core code that I write ? or any link ? thanks